# How to upload the profile link to firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, user-profile

When my "*ProfileImageuUrl* " shows up in firebase database the link is missing to the profile image, which is causing a misfire on my user profile the image won't show because there is no link in firebase database how do I restructure my code to this issue

```
if let AuthData = AuthDataResult {
                print(AuthData.user.email)
                let dict : Dictionary < String, Any> = [
                    "uid": AuthData.user.uid,
                    "email": AuthData.user.email,
                    "ProfileImageUrl": "",
                    ]
             if let profileImge = self.selectedImage, let imageData = profileImge.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
             let StorageRef = Storage.storage()
                    .reference(forURL: "gs://tunnel-vision-458d6.appspot.com/")
                let storageProfileRef = StorageRef.child("profileImage").child(AuthData.user.uid)

                let metadata = StorageMetadata()
                metadata.contentType = "profileImage.jpg"
                storageProfileRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (storageMetadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                    return
                }

                    storageProfileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                        if let metaImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                        print(metaImageUrl)
                    }


                        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(AuthData.user.uid).updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {
                            (error,ref) in
                            if error == nil {
                                print("Done")

                            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning an empty string for ProfileImageUrl in dict:

```
let dict : Dictionary < String, Any> = [
    "uid": AuthData.user.uid,
    "email": AuthData.user.email,
    "ProfileImageUrl": "",
]
```

And you never update it afterward.  The dict is written exactly as you see it here.  Assign it the value you want before writing it.

Comment: do I assign the firebase storage url or the photo image folder that its assign to

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1- Make `dict` a var

```
            var dict : Dictionary < String, Any> = [
                "uid": AuthData.user.uid,
                "email": AuthData.user.email 
                ]
```

2- Assign a value to `ProfileImageUrl` and embed updating the values inside callback of `storageProfileRef.downloadURL` where you have a url for the image

```
              storageProfileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    if let metaImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                    print(metaImageUrl)
                     dict["ProfileImageUrl"] = metaImageUrl
                    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(AuthData.user.uid).updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {
                        (error,ref) in
                        if error == nil {
                            print("Done")

                        }
                    }
               }
          }
```

Comment: the firebase storage link shows up in the database but the image do not appear when you click on the link @sh-khan

Comment: link extension is `jpg`

Comment: I'm in the motion of setting up a profile screen & The profile image the user signed up with doesn't appear on their profile because it's not appearing in firebase storage it says safari can't open specified address this code is throwing me off @sh-khan

Comment: what link extension @sh-khan